# How to enable NTLM for all intranet sites in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, ntlm

I know I can add specific URLs in the `network.authmatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` and separate them by comma delimiters, but I would like to enable NTLM for all intranet sites. I tried `http://*` and `http://.` but that didn't work. Also, some of the intranet sites are `https`.

**Update**

1. Set `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn` to `true`
2. Set `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` to blank

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You don't have to put specific URLs in the list — you can put entire domains. So, for example, adding `mycompany.com` should enable NTLM for `mail.mycompany.com`, `monitor.mycompany.com`, `intranet.mycompany.com`, &c. (You might need to do `.mycompany.com` with a leading dot, actually, i can't remember — and my current job doesn't use NTLM, so i can't test.)

You can also tell Firefox to enable NTLM for any site that doesn't have an FQDN (fully qualified domain name); this is useful if your company just uses `http://intranet` or something similar. To enable this, set `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn` to `true`.

Comment: we don't use FQDN for intranet sites, so i'll try it out when I have a chance. thank you!

Comment: @kine's first suggestion was right, I didn't have to use a leading dot or wildcards to get mycompany.com and all subdomains like dashboard.mycompany.com added.

Comment: For anyone confused why entire domains aren't working like I was, using just `mycompany.com` doesn't work. You have to use `http://mycompany.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, but the thing that worked was setting network.authmatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris to domain.com

Thats all you have to do. Trying to do individual websites like http://website.domain.com didnt work. Just use the domain name

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly. You know, consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state. Otherwise, read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: This seems to be a comment on the already-accepted answer rather than a standalone answer of its own.